# Apache Camel dynamic endpoints

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

I'm starting to learn Apache Camel and faced with the problem.

I need to read XML file from file system, parse it and transfer some file specified in this XML to another location.

---

This is example of XML located in "C:/Users/JuISe/Desktop/jms".

```
<file>
    <from>C:/Users/JuISe/Desktop/from</from>
    <to>C:/Users/JuISe/Desktop/to</to>
</file>
```

It means transfer all files from 
"C:/Users/JuISe/Desktop/from" directory to "C:/Users/JuISe/Desktop/to"

Here is my code:

```
public class FileShifter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
            context.addRoutes(new MyRouteBuilder());
            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            context.stop();
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    private String from;
    private String to;
    public void configure(){
        from("file:C:/Users/JuISe/Desktop/jms?noop=true")
                .setHeader("from", xpath("file/from/text()").stringResult())
                .setHeader("to", xpath("file/to/text()").stringResult())
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        from = exchange.getIn().getHeader("from").toString();
                        to = exchange.getIn().getHeader("to").toString();
                    }
                })
                .pollEnrich("file:" + from)
                .to("file:" + to);
    }
}
```

It doesn't works.
Here is logs:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter - Loaded 216 type converters
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry - Runtime endpoint registry is in extended mode gathering usage statistics of all incoming and outgoing endpoints (cache limit: 1000)
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint - Endpoint is configured with noop=true so forcing endpoint to be idempotent as well
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.component.file.FileEndpoint - Using default memory based idempotent repository with cache max size: 1000
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[file://C:/Users/JuISe/Desktop/jms?noop=true]
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Total 1 routes, of which 1 is started.
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.16.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 1.033 seconds
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - file://C:/Users/JuISe/Desktop/jms] WARN org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.MarkerFileExclusiveReadLockStrategy - Deleting orphaned lock file: C:\Users\JuISe\Desktop\jms\message.xml.camelLock
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - file://C:/Users/JuISe/Desktop/jms] INFO org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder - Created default XPathFactory com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl@2308d4c8
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.16.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
[main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 300 seconds. Inflights per route: [route1 = 2]
[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 299 seconds. Inflights per route: [route1 = 2]
[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 298 seconds. Inflights per route: [route1 = 2]
[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 297 seconds. Inflights per route: [route1 = 2]
[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 296 seconds. Inflights per route: [route1 = 2]
[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 295 seconds. Inflights per route: [route1 = 2]
[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Waiting as there are still 2 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 294 seconds. Inflights per route: [route1 = 2]
```

Thanks for a help!

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it? Are the files not moved as you would expect?

Comment: Yes, files absolutely not moved

Comment: Ok, well as far as I know, `pollEnrich` simply injects the contents of the file in question, but does not do anything with the physical file. I'm not sure this route will ever accomplish what you would like it to.

Comment: In fact, I want to take XML, read "from" and "to" fields from this. And replace this XML by target file in exchange.

Comment: Right, I get what you are trying to do. Just curious, does the "to" file get created as you expect it to?

Comment: No, "to" folder is remains empty

Comment: You cannot set the String values inside the processor and use it in the route outside , set it on exchange properties or out header to access it outside the processor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a bean with producer and consumer template , file end points directory cannot be dynamic

```
from("file:/Users/smunirat/apps/destination/jms?noop=true")
            .setHeader("from", xpath("file/from/text()").stringResult())
            .setHeader("to", xpath("file/to/text()").stringResult())
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    from = exchange.getIn().getHeader("from").toString();
                    to = exchange.getIn().getHeader("to").toString();

                    exchange.getOut().setHeader("from", from);
                    exchange.getOut().setHeader("to", to);

                }
            })

            .to("log:Sundar?showAll=true&multiline=true")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    ConsumerTemplate createConsumerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createConsumerTemplate();
                    ProducerTemplate createProducerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
                    Exchange receive = createConsumerTemplate.receive("file://"+exchange.getIn().getHeader("from"));
                    createProducerTemplate.sendBody("file://"+exchange.getIn().getHeader("to"),receive.getIn().getMandatoryBody());

                }
            })
            .log("Message");
```

This might require a little tweaking to change the file name and delete the original file from the from location

Comment: It seems working. Can you please explain, what is 
".to("log:Sundar?showAll=true&multiline=true")" means?
Thank you very much!